# LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma tabela no PostgreSQL. Gostaria de contar duas colunas onde uma tem mais registro que a outra. Se eu usar LEFT OUTER JOIN acho que vai funcionar, porém, não estou conseguindo com a sintaxe do PostgreSQL.
O comando que estou usando é o seguinte:

```
SELECT codmunic, ene_ine, count(loc) as energia_ine
from tabela a left join
    (SELECT codmunic, COUNT(loc) as energia_ine
      FROM tabela
      WHERE ene_ine = 's'
      GROUP BY codmunic) as ag_caim
      using (codmunic)
      group by codmunic;
```

Comment: você só quer duas colunas contando da mesma tabela ?

Comment: Qual é o erro? Tem como montar algum exemplo de como você quer que os dados sejam retornados?

Comment: Olá para avaliar melhor seria legal postar o erro que está ocorrendo.
Por cima acredito que possa estar faltando o **group by** pelo campo **ene_ine**

Comment: Rovann Linhalis, só duas colunas... depois faço pras outras, ou seja, eu pego o codmunic como base pra consultar as outras.

Comment: Camilo Santos, é esse o erro: 
ERROR:  column "ene_ine" does not exist
LINE 5:       WHERE ene_ine = 's'
                    ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "censo_escolar.ener_ine" or the column "a.ener_ine".

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "ene_ine" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "censo_escolar.ener_ine" or the column "a.ener_ine".
Character: 173

Comment: Heverton, é esse o erro: 
ERROR:  column "ene_ine" does not exist
LINE 5:       WHERE ene_ine = 's'
                    ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "censo_escolar.ener_ine" or the column "a.ener_ine".

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "ene_ine" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "censo_escolar.ener_ine" or the column "a.ener_ine".
Character: 173

Answer (score 1):

Talvez você não precise de nenhum tipo de `JOIN` para fazer essa contagem comparativa, veja só:

```
SELECT
    codmunic,
    ene_ine,
    count(loc) as energia_ine
FROM
    tabela
GROUP BY
    codmunic,
    ene_ine
ORDER BY
    codmunic,
    ene_ine;
```

Comment: Lacobus, obrigado pela força, mas eu precisei sim usar o left join. Acabei indo pra o MySQL, não consegui fazer no PostgreSQL, não deu certo. Mas eu agradeço a todos que me ajudaram. Sinceramente gostaria de usar o PostgreSQL mas quando uso algumas quareis lá, não consigo rodar igual quando eu faço no MySQL.